# "Debug Assertion" Runtime Error on VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, debugging

I'm writing a C++ MFC program on VS2008 and I'm getting this "Debug Assertion Error" when I first run the program **sometimes**. When I try to debug it, it takes me to this winhand.cpp file which is not part of the program I wrote so I'm not sure how to debug this.

It takes the error to this place in winhand.cpp

```
 CObject* pTemp = LookupTemporary(h);
 if (pTemp != NULL)
 {
  // temporary objects must have correct handle values
  HANDLE* ph = (HANDLE*)((BYTE*)pTemp + m_nOffset);  // after CObject
  ASSERT(ph[0] == h || ph[0] == NULL);
  if (m_nHandles == 2)
   ASSERT(ph[1] == h);
 }
```

So why does this error happen? Why does it only happen sometimes (50% of the time)? How would I debug this?

I'll provide some code if is needed.

THANKS!

Comment: HANDLE* ph = (HANDLE*)((BYTE*)pTemp + m_nOffset);

seems like an unusual way to extract a handle from an object

Any reason why you do it like that?

What does the LookUpTemporary() return?

Comment: Hi Anders, I have no idea. I didn't write those code, it is not part of my program. But that's where the VS2008 debug is taking me.

Comment: OIC, you probably need to start commenting out your original code to see  what piece of your code is causing this.

Comment: There are two ASSERTs there.  Which one is asserting?  If the first, what is the value of ph[0]?  If the second, what are the values of h and ph[1]?  Report values in both decimal and hex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that is asserting is part of MFC's `CHandleMap` class.  MFC deals with windows as `CWnd` objects, but Windows deals with them as `HWND` handles.  the handle map allows MFC to 'convert' an `HWND` into a pointer to the MFC object representing that object.

What the assertion seems to be doing is checking that when a lookup of the handle finds an MFC object, that the MFC object also thinks it's wrapping the same handle.

If they're different, then you get the assertion.

So it would appear that something is corrupting the handle map or the MFC object for that handle or you're doing something incorrect that gets these 2 data structures out of sync.

Some things you might do to try to debug the problem is to determine:

- what MFC object is being found in the lookup (that's what's being pointed to by `pObject`)
- what the MFC object thinks it's wrapping (that's the handle `ph[0]` and/or `ph[1]` - I'm not sure why there can be 2 of them)
- what the handle is for (that's `h`)

Do the handles look like handle values or do they look like garbage?  Does `pObject` point to something that looks like an MFC object, or garbage?  Do any of these these things seem related?

The answers to these questions may point to what you need to do next (maybe set a debug write breakpoint on the item that looks like it's trashed).

Answer (score 1):

I got this same assertion few days ago, and after some google search,
I found the solution for my case here:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?216770-What-would-cause-this-assertion

In my case, change to misused

```
CDC* dc = GetDC();
CSize spaceSize = dc->GetTextExtent(" ");
dc->DeleteDC();
```

to

```
CDC* dc = GetDC();
CSize spaceSize = dc->GetTextExtent(" ");
ReleaseDC(dc);
```

would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for code along those lines (from memory from Stroustrup's book):

```
c1 = (t2+t3).c_str();
```

(in spirit, could be other commands and expressions of course).Temporary objects are destroyed after their enclosing full expression has been evaluated, or at least the standard allows them to be. That means that what you would like to allocate to c1 may, or may not, still be in memory where it can be assigned to c1. The compiler may alert you to this issue, and the issue may or may not arise depending on what exactly you assign and other circumstances (I am not compiler writer), which would also explain why you get this error message only sometimes.

So in your shoes, I'd scan my code for similar expressions and clean them up.

Answer (score 0):

When the debugger breaks, head up the call stack to the first bit of *your* code (if there is any - hopefully there is!).  Ideally it's as simple as something in your code calling a library function incorrectly, and the library is catching the error with an assert and alerting you to that.  (I don't think anyone will be able to tell what's wrong from the *library* code, we need to see *your* code.)

Otherwise, you're in for some tricky debugging: you're doing something wrong with the library that is asserting (looks like MFC) so go back and review all your MFC code and make sure everything is correct and according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like an error I had this morning. Is this happening in OnIdle()?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but hoping that someone may get a little help from my answer.

I also faced a similar issue recently because of my simple mistake, then I came across this post and got a hint from "pac"'s post.

What I found is that if I use DeleteDC() to release DC returned from GetWindowDC() or GetDC() I will get the above assertion in MFC frame once CPaintDC object instance goes out of scope.

```
CDC * pDC = GetWindowDC();
...
ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

You have to use DeleteDC() only in conjunction with CreateDC() API.

```
CDC * pDC = new CDC();
pDC->CreateDC();
....
pDC->DeleteDC();
```

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem when some of our project dlls were linking MFC as static library and some as shared library (check "Use of MFC" in Project settings)